# Django 2 django.core.exceptions.AppRegistryNotReady: Models aren't loaded yet

Tags: python, django, django-channels, django-2.0

I currently have a django app running Django==2.0.

I wasn't having this problem before but yesterday when I was running through some code I got the error

```
from home.models import Notification
ImportError: cannot import name 'Notification'
```

This was from `meetings/models.py` which is an app at the same level as mange.py

My apps are registered as following

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',

    'home', 
    'meetings', 
]
```

If I simple import home and then print it out I see

`<module 'home' from '<relative_path>/home/__init__.py'>`

But if I try something like this

`from django.apps import apps
print(apps.get_models())`

I get the error `django.core.exceptions.AppRegistryNotReady: Models aren't loaded yet.`

After that I tried testing the same thing through `python manage.py shell` and I got completely different results.

`apps.get_models()` returned all of the models I was expecting to see and that are in the database.

`>>> apps.get_app_config('home').models['notification']` returned `<class 'home.models.Notification'>`

I'm trying to figure out why I can't import Notification in my meetings models and why I'm getting different results when I run these commands in the shell.

I also have django channels and storages as installed apps.

Comment: from where you are running from home.models import Notification
?

Comment: Please show the full traceback of the error. Do you have a circular import (`home` importing from `meeting.models` as well as `meeting` importing from `home.models`)? If so, show how you are using the imported models in both apps.

Comment: That could be the problem. In my meetings app I import models from my home app. And from my home app I import models from me meeting app. What is the fix on that?

Comment: The circular import was the problem. For some reason I had added in an import in my home app models that was unnecessary. For future reference for me or others what would be the solution if a circular import was needed? Or is that considered bad practice?